# Eclipse RCP plugin GUI refresh issue

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am trying to adapt code from AWT to eclipse SWT plugin.I'm facing refresh issue.I have view with table(AWT) and another view with  chart(AWT). Individually they are fine but when i'm add both i'm facing refresh issue only on chart view, any advises ?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I had to do to embed a JPanel in an SWT view.

```
        Composite videoComposite = new Composite(panel, 
                SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.BORDER | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
        videoComposite.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        videoComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(
                SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true, 1, 1));

        CLabel videoImage = new CLabel(videoComposite, SWT.SHADOW_IN);
        videoImage.setImage(dummyVideo);

        frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(videoComposite);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setLookAndFeel();
                applet = new JApplet();
                applet.setFocusCycleRoot(false);
                mediaPanel = rabidVideo.getVideoPanel(false);
                applet.add(mediaPanel);
                frame.add(applet);
            }
        });
```

where `frame` is a `Frame`, `applet` is a `JApplet`, and `mediaPanel` is an extension of `JPanel`.

Here's `setLookAndFeel`:

```
protected void setLookAndFeel() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        EclipseLogging.logError(RabidPlugin.getDefault(),
                    RabidPlugin.PLUGIN_ID, e);
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        EclipseLogging.logError(RabidPlugin.getDefault(),
                    RabidPlugin.PLUGIN_ID, e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        EclipseLogging.logError(RabidPlugin.getDefault(),
                    RabidPlugin.PLUGIN_ID, e);
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        EclipseLogging.logError(RabidPlugin.getDefault(),
                    RabidPlugin.PLUGIN_ID, e);
    }
}
```